# javascript function(e){}, but not passing any parameter when executing

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I see functions with parameter like this:

```
$('#my_div').bind("mouseover mouseenter", function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    var el = $("#" + e.type);
    var n = el.text();

    el.text(++n);
});
```

I don't get what is being passed into the function. I would understand it if it is something like `(function(e){ .... }(parameter);` but it is not. Can someone shade some light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always a parameter being passed, it's just that you're not the one passing it directly. The browser is.

In this case, you're talking about the event handlers. Basically what happens is that when the event is triggered, the browser will pass an event object to the callback of the event listener (the callback you provided).

If you want to know what's inside the event object, look into this mozilla docs page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

If you want to know how browsers handle the whole passing of event object, here's the specification: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#the-event-handler-processing-algorithm look under 4) where it says "process the event E as follows"

Comment: that a jquery event object, so it's not the browser passing it. same idea though...

Comment: True, technically jQuery wraps the whole process. But in the end, the event will have to be passed at some point by the browser. Plus, it gets confusing when you start to separate what Javascript does and what the encapsulated jQuery does when the end result is the same.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery will actually call that function, since functions are first class citizen objects in JavaScript, so it can be passed as an argument. `e` is for event args which jQuery will provide.

This pattern is called "callback".

Answer (score 1):

The function isn't actually being called yet.  This is telling the browser to call that function for you when the 'mouseover' or 'mouseenter' event happens.  In this case, when the browser does that it will pass an event object which will get bound to the local variable `e` in side of the function.